# How can you create a analytics program that can track API calls

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, user-tracking

I want to create a tracker for users on my website that shows what API calls they are using and how long it takes for them to load. Ideally, I would be able to put each user's session under their ID number to be able to see what everyone is using for analytics purposes and to see what can be improved timing wise. Is this something that can be done through Google Analytics or would I have to write it completely. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of tracking, I believe it could be achievable with the [userTiming](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings) tracking within `Google Analytics`

The real-time reporting, on the other hand, will be much trickier, as I believe the reporting is at the aggregated level.

The same GA document references a mozilla document on 
[navigation timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API), which could be of interest to you (but I am not familiar with it myself, unfortunately). It seems that it might do what you need.